# how to remove lockScaling fabricJS?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have assigned `object.lockScaling = true` when it reach to specific width and then scaling facility disabled. However I need to increase the width but not to decrease beyond the specific width. How to do that? Here is my code.

```
if(obj.getHeight() > obj.canvas.height || obj.getWidth() > obj.canvas.width){
              obj.lockScalingX=true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a `scaling` event  in fabricjs so we can use that for this.You want some thing like this..

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width:100,
  height:100
  })
canvas.add(rect)

canvas.on('object:scaling', function(options) {
  console.log(rect.getWidth());
  if(rect.getWidth() > canvas.getWidth() || rect.getHeight() > canvas.getHeight())
    {
      
      rect.lockScalingX=true
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: actually I want to remove lockScalingX to increase a width.